# Saving dataframe to .txt or .csv file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, output, bigdata

I'm working on a machine learning algorithm to predict the price of ethereum. I already have a small dataset for which I am doing the predictions. I can print the predictions in the terminal and I am able to see them. However, I'm not able to save them as a text/csv file. This is the code that I have

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark
import datetime

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Ethereum').getOrCreate()
 #get csv file as a DataFram object
data = spark.read.csv('hdfs://andromeda.student.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/user/cln31/ethereum', header=True,inferSchema=True)

#DataFrame type
data = data.select(data.date.cast("int"),
                    data.PriceBTC.cast("float"),
                    data.PriceUSD.cast("float"),
                    data.TxCnt.cast("float"),
                    data.TxTfrValMedUSD.cast("float"),
                    data.CapMrktCurUSD.cast("float"),
                    data.IssContUSD.cast("float"),
                    data.TxTfrValMeanUSD.cast("float"),
                    data.TxTfrValUSD.cast("float"))


data.printSchema()

featureassembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=["date","TxTfrValMedUSD","CapMrktCurUSD","TxCnt","TxTfrValUSD", "IssContUSD", "TxTfrValMeanUSD"],outputCol="Independent Features")
output = featureassembler.setHandleInvalid("skip").transform(data)
output.show()

output.select("Independent Features").show()

finalized_data=output.select("Independent Features","PriceUSD")
finalized_data.show()

train_data,test_data=finalized_data.randomSplit([0.75,0.25])

regressor=LinearRegression(featuresCol='Independent Features', labelCol='PriceUSD')
regressor=regressor.fit(train_data)

test_data1 = output.filter(data.date >= 1455408000) #2016.02.14
test_data1 = test_data1.filter(test_data1.date <= 1561852800) #2019.06.30

test_data1 = test_data1.select("Independent Features","PriceUSD")

test_data1.show()


pred_results=regressor.evaluate(test_data1)
pred_results.predictions.describe().show()

pred_results.predictions.write.csv("partCOut.csv")
```

I basically want to save the output of pred_results.predictions. This is the error that I get:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'CSV data source does not support `struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>` data type.;'

Comment: so what do I do to save it as a text file?

Comment: you convert every columns to string*

Comment: or save it as json

Comment: As @Steven mentions, the best way to keep the structure is saving it as `json`, otherwise you will need to convert every column or maybe parse the array to save it as string column.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird.  I dealt with something like this recently.  I believe the issue was that the object I was trying to save was not an actual dataframe.  Converting it into a dataframe fixed the problem, and then I could save the file (in my scenario, it was going to a SQL server table).

Try something like this.

```
# your code...
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

display(df)

# convert python df to spark df
spark_df = spark.createDataframe(df)
# write df out as table
spark_df.write.csv("/rawdata/AAA.csv")
```

To check the type of the object, try this.

```
z = []
type(z)
<type 'list'>

z = ()
type(z)
<type 'tuple'>
```